# Discord bot python echo command image

Tags: python, image, discord, command, echo

I have a command that bot echo my messages, but if I paste the image, bot has an error and I dont know how to fix it. I want my bot will be able to use the echo command and insert the photo I pasted.

I tried to fix this, but i don't know how to do it with images, there's no tutorials with echo command and images

that's my code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['echo'])
@commands.is_owner()
async def e(ctx, *, message=None):
    message = message or "Napisz co chcesz powtórzyć"
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include some more logic within your command.

What you are looking for is either a new parameter, called `image` or some checking within your code.

**Option 1:** Make a new parameter called `image: discord.Attachment = None`

This way it is optional, and you don't need to include an image in every command. You can then check for the image within your code by using `if image` and include the logic to send it.

**Option 2:** Include some logic within your code and just check if the message contains an image.

```py
if ctx.message.attachments: # If the message contains an image
    attachment = ctx.message.attachments[0]
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(content=message, file=discord.File(attachment.url))
else:
   await ctx.message.delete()
   await ctx.send(content=message)
```